# jQuery number of URL validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need a validation that a string cannot contain more than 1 URL. Maximum length of string may be 500 characters. Is there any efficient way to calculate number of URL with less time complexity?
Thanks.

Here's what I've currently tried:

```
var count = 0; 
var urlArray = urlstring.split(" "); 

$.each( urlArray, function( i, val ) { 
    if(val != "") { 
        var flag = val.match(/^((http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)|)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=‌​&%@!\-\/]))?$/); 

        if(flag) {
            count++; 
        } 
    } 
});
```

Comment: *'Minimum length of string may be 500'* - You mean maximum, right?

Comment: Yes right.Maximum may be 500 chars.

Comment: [**String.length**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

Comment: @George I need a validation that a string cannot contain more than 1 URL, how can i do with String.length ?

Comment: Will the urls always be separated by at least one space?

Comment: @soktinpk No that is not mandatory. String may be looks like this : "This is an url http://www.google.com and another.https://www.yahoo.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

```
function countNumberOfUrl(urlstring)
{
   var number = 0;
   var count = urlstring.match(/\http:|https:/g).length;
   if(count)
   {
     number = count;
   }
   return number;
}
```